# Forgot to create a new branch before pushing to remote

Tags: git, github, branch, rebase, branching-and-merging

I was working on a feature locally and made a couple of commits on my master branch (instead of making a separate branch and working there). Then, I pushed those commits to my remote master branch on GitHub (which is actually a fork of another repository). Some time passed before I realized the error and more commits were added to the remote master branch. Now, I want to go back and make a separate branch for that initial feature. How would I do that?

To illustrate my problem, this is what I have:

```
master A - B - C - D - E - F
```

This is what I want:

```
newbranch     C - D
             /     \
master A - B  ----  E - F
```

where commits `C, D` are the initial feature that I forgot to make a new branch for.

Comment: So you don't actually want C and D on `master`? Is it the case that both E and F don't depend on anything in C or D?

Comment: And, if you want to remove commits from `master`, is everyone who uses this repo OK with rewriting the recent history of `master`? (In large teams, or public repos, the answer is usually, No.)

Comment: The way you've drawn your picture of the two branches is misleading, and this *may* be important (it's not obvious to me whether it is important): Git commits are not "stuck" on a branch once made. Git commits are first *made*, after which many branch names are allowed to contain *any given set of commits*. If `newbranch` contains commit `D`, and commit `D` links back to commit `C`, and commit `C` links back to commit `B`, and `master` contains commit `B`, then *both branches* contain commit `B`.

Comment: I recommend working your way through [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), after which you'll draw your branches differently. :-)

Comment: @torek I was thinking the same thing. Then I decided I'm 90% sure I know what OP is asking, despite the picture being incorrect. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caveat**: it's generally considered bad practice to rewrite shared branches such as `master`. You'll want to make sure everyone who uses the repo is aware that you're doing this.

That being said, as asked, you could do this:

```
# NOTE - this assumes your remote is called "origin"

git fetch

# create a branch called "newbranch" that points to commit hash D
git branch newbranch D

# checkout master so you can fix it up
git switch master

# change master to point to B
git reset --hard B

# Replay E through F (or any new commits if they exist!) onto master
git cherry-pick E..origin/master

# replace the remote master (make sure everyone is OK with it!)
git push --force-with-lease
```

The results of these commands will make your two branches look like:

```
newbranch: A-B-C-D
master: A-B-E'-F'
```

Note the `E'` and `F'` notation indicates that those commits will be similar to E and F, but with different commit IDs (because anytime you rewrite a commit you are literally making a *new* commit, and therefore the ID will change.)

**Some Thoughts:**

1. It's possible you'll get conflicts at the cherry-pick command. This will happen if any of the commits after `D` depend on either of the commits you are pulling out of `master`. If that happens you may want to reconsider this action altogether.
2. In Git there are oftentimes many different ways to do the same thing. Note you can actually swap out the `reset` and `cherry-pick` commands and do it all in one shot with a single "fancy" `rebase --onto`. But conceptually I think doing a reset and then cherry-picking a range of commits is easier to understand explicitly. The rebase just does both behind the scenes.
3. In the cherry-pick command, the reason I suggest going from commit `E` to `origin/master` instead of the obvious `E` to `F`, is simply because you mentioned: "more commits were added to the remote master branch." In case even more are added that you don't know about until your initial `git fetch` command at the start of this answer, this way you will keep any new unknown commits as well.

Comment: Thanks @TTT. Let me explain the situation more clearly. Basically, I was working on adding documentation for a project and I forgot to make a new branch before pushing to my fork of the repository and creating my PR. And before I realised it, my PR was merged and those commits . Everything that I did is entirely independent of what has been done before/after. However now, those commits are included on my master branch history, and everytime I do a new PR, those commits are also included in the PR because they are considered "ahead" of the main repository and it is a mess.

Comment: Also, since this is a fork and nobody uses it except me, would it mess up the main repository? (I have done several PR's)

Comment: @NicolasBoyer I'm pretty sure you don't want C and D on `master`, right? So `master` would become A-B-E'-F' ? (I use E' and F' there because the commit IDs will change, but the contents of the changes would be the same as E and F.)

Comment: @NicolasBoyer If the answer is yes, (you don't want C and D on `master` at all), then you would need to remove the line going from D to E. Note that you would leave the line going from B to C, because `newbranch` becomes: A-B-C-D.

Comment: @NicolasBoyer I've updated my answer to show what the resulting branches will be. I think that's what you want. And, what you do in your fork won't touch the original repo, unless (or until) you push something to it.